# How to prevent eclipse c/c++ unit testing from encountering XML parse error which leads to runner hanging?

Tags: c++, eclipse, unit-testing, boost, eclipse-cdt

Simply put:

When I execute the tests using boost runner I get the following error and the c/c++ unit testing hangs.

```
XML parse error: The entity name must immediately follow the '' in the entity reference.
```

How do I avoid this from happening?

FYI:
 The test runners run perfectly fine from the command line outside of eclipse, or in a debug window in eclipse, so it must be an eclipse issue isolated in the "c/c++ unit console".

Im running Kepler.

Gracias.

Comment: You should... probably include the offending XML file. Run it through a validator (`xmllint`?)

Comment: I dont see an xml file in my build directory or the eclipse workspace directory. Where would that xml file be located?

Comment: I'd look for (hidden?) files named e.g. `.project`, for a start

Comment: I inspected and grepped the .project file, but nothing is in there.

Comment: Well. We're not a flying support squad and our psychic abilities do not _quite_ include remote computer access. If you can't find the cause of the error, perhaps it's an idea to start over. Live with source control, and inspect the change whenever the issue recurs.

Comment: I inspected and grepped the .project file, but nothing is in there. It must be parsing a temporary file, but I dont know where it is. Or maybe I dont know how to make it persist...? I guess I need to dig and see how the c/c++ unit test run configuration in eclipse actually runs. Any links would help. I tried to edit my previous comment and add to it, but I kept getting silly 5 sec rules even after waiting

Answer (score 0):

If you put a `BOOST_CHECK` inside a test stub, and the tested code is multithreaded, the asynchronous `<Info>` output will probably corrupt the XML output. Check the XML output carefully to spot what is the offending test.

At least up to 1.57, while validating stub usage is also important for unit-testing modules, Boost.Test is not considered thread-safe in this context.

You could probably work around the problem by [redirecting the output stream](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/test/doc/html/utf/user-guide/test-output/log-ct-config.html#utf.user-guide.test-output.log.ct-config.output-stream) and overloading `boost::unit_test::unit_test_log.set_stream`.